# Simple question on hall effect sensor

Tags: hall-effect

[image]

I am using the a hall effect sensor - model 480-5198-ND. I have tested this simple circuit using a LED and it is working. However, it is "ON" by default. Only when the magnet is near the hall effect sensor , it will be "OFF".

How do I make it such that it is OFF by default and ON only when the magnet is near the hall effect sensor?

Comment: 480-5198-ND is a Digikey stock number - it would be much better to give the manufacturer's part number, which Digikey gives as Honeywell SS449R.  From the Honeywell datasheet, the thing can only sink 20 mA, so the 50 Ohm pull-up resistor you show is much too low - you should use at least 250 Ohms.

Comment: Hall sensors come in both NO and NC types.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is to add an inverter circuit to the output of the Hall sensor.

Some Hall sensors may be sensitive to the N versus S poles of the magnet and will change their output when you flip the magnet. This would be more the case with a linear type of Hall sensor.